# Package explorer doesn't mark files modified locally

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-indigo

Yellow SVN icon, revision number and ">" doesn't appear in my package explorer (in SVN project). CVS projects looks OK.

[image: how it should look]

How can I change it?

[image: installed plugins]

[image: preferences]

[image]

[image: visible team options]

Comment: Is it package explorer specific or you're getting the same problem in Navigator, Project explorer or in any other view?

Comment: The same problem in Navigator view.

Comment: Select any project, right click on it & go to Team. What options are you able to see there?

Comment: I have added screenshots

Comment: You should check View Settings in Preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to **Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations** and check **SVN**.

Comment: THX. As I remember my solution was to re install SVN connectors.